# How to know if the element is last element in vector using for(int i:myVector) code style?

Tags: c++

```
for(int& i:myVector){
   ...
}
```

is there any method to know if i is the last element using this code style without using extra variables or methods (e.g.:count,myVector.size())?

like

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=myVector.begin();it!=myVector.end();++it){
    if(it!=end()-1){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. Why do you care about the last element? What are you going to do differently with it?

Comment: Are you changing each element of the vector or only reading it? I don't know what logic you're using, but it may make sense to make a new vector that contains everything but the last element of the first.

Or, it may make sense to let your loop operate on the last element, and then fix things up afterward.

Comment: Would "if (&i == &myVector.back())" be considered cheating?  :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO, there is no way of finding out the index without using an auxiliary count. The range-based notation is hiding the index from you and gives you the dereferenced iterator. The range-based `for` is equivalent to ([from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)):

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
    __end = end_expr; 
    __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

If you need index-based access, then use plain old iterators.